# else statement being executed when if is expected to run

Tags: php

I have a feature on my site where users who have befriended each other can view each others photos. For example, if I am logged in as `Conor`, and I want to view `Alice's` photos, Conor must befriend Alice, and Alice must befriend Conor - they must be mutual friends.

I have a table in my database called `favourites` - which stores all friend requests. Lets assume `favourites` has two rows:

```
   id: 1
   favourited_who: Alice
   favourited_by: Conor

   id: 2
   favourited_who: Conor
   favourited_by: Alice
```

They both have each other `favourited`.

Consider the following snippet:

```
<?php
$get_favs_q = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM favourites");
        $getting_favs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_favs_q);
            $user_favourited = $getting_favs['favourited_who'];
            $user_favourited_by = $getting_favs['favourited_by'];
        /*************************/     
        if ($user == $username  || $user_favourited == $user && $user_favourited_by == $username 
                                || $user_favourited == $username && $user_favourited_by == $user){

            // $user = name in the URL after ?= - As we are on Alice's page .. $user equals Alice
            // $username = session variable for logged in user - $username = Conor

            // If both users have each other favourited, then the code to display images appears here.
        } else {
            echo "  <span style='margin-left: 10px;'> 
                        You and $ufirstname must favourite each other to view each others backstage. 
                    </span>";
        }
?>
```

I have covered all scenario's to check whether the `$user` has favourited the `$username` and vice versa, but, the else statement is always being executed, echoing the message and I don't understand why.

Comment: echo out the different values to check if you're getting the correct data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parenthesis around your checks like so:

```
if (
    $user == $username  
    || ($user_favourited == $user && $user_favourited_by == $username)
    || ($user_favourited == $username && $user_favourited_by == $user) ){
    // Do your thing
} else {
    // Do the other thing
}
```

The problem is that one of the "ands" is always going to be false, so the whole statement is always false. You can shorten your statement to the following:

```
A or B and C or D and E
```

Which is logically the same as

```
A or B or D and C and E
```

And since `C = !E`, the statement is always false. What you really want, and what I showed above is:

```
A or (B and C) or (D and E)
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I'm starting to understand the approach you have mentioned above. I have changed my code, and applied your if statement above, but, unfortunately, it is still executing the else statement?

Comment: @Freddy Then there is probably something wonky with your data. I would print it out so you can inspect it and ensure the values are what they should be. Having said that, the logic issue would still have been a problem so its good you got that fixed too.

Comment: Ah, turns out all I needed was to execute a while loop on this line `while ($getting_favs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_favs_q)){`. But yes, as you said, it was better that the if statement was sorted earlier to avoid issues further down the line. Thank you again!